# Jinja2: Word experienced an error trying to open the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, jinja2, python-docx

I admit the question is vague, but that's the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKHUI.png) I'm getting.

I'm trying to create a word document template using a derivative of the python-docx library called [python-docx-template](https://pypi.org/project/docxtpl/), which is using Jinja2.

What I'm doing is generating the data I need using Python, and then sending it to the docx template that I'm building, so that the document outputs the data in a format I want.

My Jinja2 template looks something like this:

```
{% if EXCHANGE_RATE %} 
{%- for stringData in EXCHANGE_RATE %}
{{stringData}}
{%- endfor %}
{%- endif %}
```

Note that the template code is within a table cell. The entire data is supposed to be generated within the cell itself(ie. not separated by rows).

What is supposed to happen here is that the template checks for the existence of `EXCHANGE_RATE` list variable (because I may or may not return this data depending on situation) and then loops the data, resulting in something like this:

```
Exchange Rate:-
1 EUR= 1.0 USD
1 EUR= 1.0 GBP
```

For some reason, the `if endif` code seems to add some extra line spacing which I do not want(without it, the output is exactly what I want), hence the usage of the `-` at various parts.
The issue I have lies in the last line: `{%- endif %}`.

If I add an extra `-` at the back (like so `{%- endif -%}` ), it somehow causes an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKHUI.png) whenever I generate and try to open the file, but I'm not exactly sure why.
I have a similar `if endif` nested `for` loop elsewhere and it will cause a similar issue, also at its own final `{%- endif %}` line.

Any suggestions?
Please note I'm still relatively new to Jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the path of your word file in the trusted locations. for this purpose open MS word -> file -> options -> trust center setting -> trusted location -> add new location
and add the location the template is located in

after that you should not get word experienced error.
I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Edit` from word file's context menu. Or you can disable `protected view` for all documents from `Trusted Center settings` at the end.